# Is tail-recursion in C always faster then classic recursion, and if yes how do i fix my code?

Tags: c, performance, recursion, tail-recursion

I am mathematics student, but i also have few programming courses this year, and in one of them we are using C to learn some "basic" programing techniques, one of them is recursion. So I find out that tail-recursion in general should be faster then classic recursion due to optimization of gcc compiler (cleaning call stack i guess), and i tried in example function that should sum all elements of given array, and i timed it, but i get way better time for regular recursion then tail one (or i just didn't implemented it well enough)

First i tought that its problem caused by my machine (hehe), but when i tried it on 2 other pc-s I eliminated that. I also tried passing pointer for variable that hold the returning value but that also didnt fixed my problem.

This is code for tail version:

```
long sum1(int arr[],int start,int len,long acom){
  if(start==len){
    return acom;
  }
  return sum1(arr,start+1,len,arr[start]+acom);
}
```

This is regular one:

```
long sum2(int arr[],int start,int len){
  if(start==len){
    return 0;
  }
  return (arr[start]+sum2(arr,start+1,len));
}
```

Calls to functions:

```
long s1=sum1(arr,0,len,0L);
long s2=sum2(arr,0,len);
```

I expected s1 to be faster but..

```
s1 = 0.000192 seconds
s2 = 0.000017 seconds
```

Also I used

```
gcc sum.c -o sum -O3
```

to compile program.

Comment: Better to just use iteration in the first place, since that's what you want the computer to actually do. Tail-call optimization isn't super reliable anyway. But it's also harder than you'd expect to implement benchmarking properly.

Comment: I know that iteration is faster in general case (see [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function) ) but I'm asking in this case particulary how can I implement/fix tail function so its actually faster then regular recursion.

Comment: You'l probably have to use longer test arrays, and repeated runs, to get a good idea about the execution time.

Comment: I use test arrays with 10000 elements for tests, and I use repeated runs, but still tail-recursion is for some reason slower.

Comment: Also, contrary to expectations, `-O3` can often generate *worse* real-world code than `-Os`, since L1i matters. (Also, from the asm I get, GCC is doing TCO on both versions)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Don't worry about this unless it's actually causing a performance problem. [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization). Most of the time the difference is negligible. Write it in the way that's most clear to the reader, worry about performance later if necessary.

Comment: The tail recursion version has to push 4 arguments per call, which takes longer than pushing 3 arguments per call.  Whether that accounts for the whole difference (or even a measurable portion of the difference) is another matter, but it is one factor.  I suspect it will be measurable; it may even be significant.

Comment: @Barman I'm now that new to programming.. i know that its not that important but i was trying it for the sake of practice.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I tried making  _acom_  and _len_ a global variables but its still slower then classic version.

Comment: @o11c Tried that too :) . Still slower.

Comment: @Shawn I also tried with 10^5 elements and its slight improvement (from 6 times slower to less then 2 times). So thats probably the answer to my question. Actual code  is faster but just slightly, so unless i have huge, like really huge amount of data, or more complex function, tail-recursion is not necessarily faster. Thanks!

Comment: Post your benchmarking code. For me, `gcc` compiles the two functions to code with nearly identical vectorized loops.

Comment: What sort of performance do you get from `int sum3(int *arr, int len) { if (len <= 0) return 0; return arr[0] + sum3(arr + 1, len - 1); }`?  It ought to be quicker since it has fewer parameters to pass.  You could write `*arr` instead of `arr[0]`; that won't affect the performance, though.

Comment: @EOF For array with 10^5 elements, on average (1000 samples) i get s1 = 0.000092 seconds, s2 = 0.000001 seconds, s3 = 0.000001 seconds (s3 is function Jonathan Leffler suggested).Those are results on Intel Celeron N3060@1.60GHz and 4 GiB.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler That kinda speed things up.

Comment: @mark That doesn't answer the question I asked. An average is also not a very good measure. Do you always run the three benchmarks in the same order? In the same process? On the same array? Where does the array come from? What is the median execution time for each function?

Comment: @EOF Oh sorry.. This is the [code](https://pastebin.com/eL8kny6e) i used to test functions.  I know its not best implementation but its the simplest i could think of at the time.

Comment: @mark post the benchmarking code as part of the [mre] please.

Comment: @EOF You didnt even bothered reading it.. but fine.. I made it even [shorter](https://pastebin.com/pmv5e0Vx). If you want it even shorter just delete all the whitespaces.......

Comment: @mark If you read the link at [mre], you'll find that you are supposed to post the code **in your question**. I'm not going to follow your pastebin link, among other reasons because that would invalidate any answer I give based on the question once the pastebin link disappears.